# Eclipse CDT: Stopping at Configuring GDT

Tags: eclipse, debugging, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have followed this guide to config Eclipse CDT. [guide for Eclipse CDT](http://www.dcs.vein.hu/bertok/oktatas/cpp_by_eclipse/eclipse_for_cpp_on_windows.html#Install_gdb)

After I follow, I can run program on C++. But, when I debug it. In progress windows, it always stop at: `Configuring GDB` (84%)

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/831861/?srch=configuring+GDB#msg_831861

My solution was to install eclipse helios.